# Join two tables, using value from the first unless it is null, otherwise use value from the second

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, null

I have three tables which look like those:

TABLE 1

```
id    j_id

1     1
2     2
3     3
```

TABLE 2

```
id    j_id     table1_id

1     57       1
2     84       1
3     1        1
4     9        2
5     2        2
```

and every *j* has a value in a third table

```
id    value

1     1abc
2     2bcd
3     3abc
57    57abc
84    84abc
9     9abc
```

I am trying to write a query which will join table 1 and table 2 and use the *J value* from the third table instead of the *j_id*, **but** the problem is that I want to use the j value from the second table if it exists and otherwise use the value from the first table.

in order the make it clearer this is my query result without using the third table:

```
tbl1.j_id    tbl2.j_id

1            1
1            84
1            57
2            2
2            9
3            null
```

I want the end query result to use the second table's *j* value unless it is null:

```
tbl1.j_id    tbl2.j_id    j_id

1            1            1abc
1            84           84abc
1            57           57abc
2            2            2abc
2            9            9abc
3            null         3abc
```

(Question and title edits are more than welcome, weren't that sure how to phrase them..)

Comment: Check ifnull function and do a join by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `JOIN` to `table3` on the `COALESCE` of `table2.j_id` and `table1.j_id`:

```
SELECT t1.j_id AS t1_j_id, t2.j_id AS t2_j_id, t3.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = COALESCE(t2.j_id, t1.j_id)
```

Output:

```
t1_j_id t2_j_id value
1       1       1abc
1       57      57abc
1       84      84abc
2       2       2bcd
2       9       9abc
3       null    3abc
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tdi4RyaRvu5DUDQfXGtP63/1)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to `left join` table3 twice:

```
select
    t1.j_id,
    t2.j_id,
    coalesce(t31.value, t32.value) j_value
from 
    table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
    left join table3 t31 on t31.id = t2.j_id
    left join table3 t32 on t32.id = t1.j_id
```

Comment: Chose the other answer because it used less joins and merged the rows within the join (and I assume leads to better performance)
But this answer was very useful in order to get what coalesce is and use it in another problem of mine :)

Comment: Yes I think that you did the good choice: the solution of @Nick is probably more efficient than mine, since it does only one `join`.